# How i load in a loop vvariables that are passed as parameters its possible?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function Qnt_Box(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var Vpanel = app.getElementById('Vpanel');
  app.getElementById('button2').setVisible(false);
  var qnt = e.parameter.Quant;
  var grid2 = app.createGrid(qnt, 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < qnt ; i++) {
    grid2.setWidget(i, 0, app.createLabel(i + 1 + ' :'));
    grid2.setWidget(i, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('x' + i)); HERE!!!
  }
  Vpanel.add(grid2);
  return app;
}
```

How do I load the variables, which were named in a looping, looping one another?

My Idea was:

```
function example() {
for(var i =0; i < qnt+1; i++)
  var aux = e.parameter.'x' + i;
}
```

but not work XS

Thank you!!

Comment: what is `'x' + i` ? Is that the name of a global variable?

Comment: Why are you using separate `x0`, `x1`, etc. instead of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name is in a property of `e.parameter`, you can use Bill's suggestion

```
e.parameter['x' + i];
```

If  it's a global variable, you can access it through the window object

```
window['x' + i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely follow your code, but if you are trying to access a property using a variable name, you can use array notation.

```
function example() {
for(var i =0; i < qnt+1; i++)
  var aux = e.parameter['x' + i];
}
```